# Using jQuery to target a <b> element when it is the ONLY content in a <p>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tags, children, targeting

I am importing via RSS various news articles from various sources (all beyond my coding/formatting control) into my client's database (all legal!) and I am attempting to standardize some of their styling for presentation on client's site via jQuery. For example...

Many many sites use various header tags seemingly for formatting only. When these are pulled into client's presentation they look like crap, so I have working code to find and replace these code blocks with a styled paragraph (the semantics of this code are not important, we mainly link back to original source), and it works fine. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selector h1, #selector h2:not(.article_name), #selector h3, #selector h4, #selector h5').replaceWith(function() {
        return '<p class="h_replace">' + $(this).text() + '</p>';
    });
});
```

The `.h_replace` CSS simply enlarges the `<p>` and adds some other attributes to make it more heading-like. So far, so good.

But here's where I'm hitting a wall: same sites also often use a `<p>` immediately followed with a child `<b>` *as the only content* to substitute/act as a `heading`.

I want to find and replace these code blocks with a styled paragraph (as above), but I am **unsuccessful** selecting any `<p>` that contains **ONLY** a `<b>` element. That is to say I want to select this:

```
<p><b>Some content here.</b></p>
```

and not this:

```
<p><b>Some Bold Text:</b> and some NOT bold text.</p>
```

In the first example, the `<p>` contains ONLY a child `<b>` element. In the second example the `<p>` contains a child `<b>` element as well as paragraph text not enclosed in the child `<b>`.

I am looking to programmatically select only the first type of `<p>`, and not the second.

Any ideas?

Here's what I've got so far, but it selects both instances:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selector p b:only-child').parent('p').replaceWith(function() {
        return '<p class="h_replace">' + $(this).text() + '</p>';
    });
});
```

The `:only-child` selector I thought would be a magic bullet, but then, of course, the `<b>` **IS** the only child of the `<p>` in both cases.

I need to select paragraphs that contain *only* and *nothing but* `<b>` content.

I hope that's clear.
As always, any help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if the `<b>` element itself contains other elements, for example `<p><b>Some <i>content</i> here.</b></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var els = $('p').filter(function() {
    return /^<(b)>.+<\/\1>$/.test($.trim($(this).html()));
});
```

It will get you all `p` that have an only children `b` without any text nodes. You can change `(b)` with whatever tag in the code above.

**Edit:** Don't know why the downvote but this works just fine:

- `<p><b>Something</b></p> // true`
- `<p>  <b>Something</b> </p> // true`
- `<p><b>Something</b> lorem</p> // false`
- `<p>lorem <b>Something</b></p> // false`
- `<p><span><b>Something</b></span></p> // false`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/LFt8x/

Comment: This did it to select. Followed up with a replaceWith to remove the existing <b> and all worked well. See final answer for final code. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) in order to verify that the `<p>` element only has one child node and that node is a `<b>` element:

```
$("#selector p").filter(function() {
    var $contents = $(this).contents();
    return $contents.length == 1 && $contents.eq(0).is("b"); 
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return "<p class='h_replace'>" + $(this).text() + "</p>";
});
```

Comment: Not working. Test page here: http://bit.ly/UqWtH9 Third paragraph down contains a <p> with only a <b> as content. It's just bolded.

Comment: @dashard, see these line breaks around the `<b>` element in the page source? They are text nodes. The `<p>` element actually has three children, including these two text nodes. Your question is about matching `<p>` elements that only have one child node (maybe you want to update it). You can see the code working on such an element in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rqdn/).

Comment: Ah, yes. I see. Your code does indeed work on **clean code**, but since I cannot account for the quality of the imported html, let alone line breaks, it's still not bullet-proof enough for this task. Or am I missing something? (Thanks for your input and efforts!)

Answer (score 0):

[elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) answer did the trick to select the text properly. Again, demo page is [here](http://bit.ly/UqWtH9).

Final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pbs = $('#selector p').filter(function() {
        return /^<(b)>.+<\/\1>$/.test($.trim($(this).html()));
    });

    pbs.replaceWith(function() {
        return '<p class="h_replace">' + $(this).text() + '</p>';
    }).addClass('h_replace2').css('width', '100%');

});
```

StackOverflow is the greatest. Thanks to everyone who piped in! Saved me hours (and by hours I mean days!!) Thanks!